# Same source query in two SSIS packages but Difference is result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

SSIS Package1:
step1) DFT Source Query:

```
select * from (Select c1,c2,c3,Rownum from ABC) t where t.Rownum=1
```

SSIS Package2:
Step1) Query in Execute SQL Task:

```
Select c1,c2,c3,Rownum into #Temp from ABC
```

step2)  DFT Source Query:

```
select * from #Temp where Rownum=1
```

When I run these two packages and insert the resultset in two different tables like TableA and TableB respectively and check the results using Except sql operator as shown below, the result is not zero records instead there is some difference in resultset and gives records.

```
select * from TableA
except
select * from TableB
```

I need help that how exactly can i debug this issue as the source query is same in both the packages.

Comment: I do not think `Rownum` will always stamp same row number to same row for different queries. WHich means for two different SQL may return different values. This can be cause of your problem.

Comment: better use `row_number() Over (partition by mycol order by order_col) as Rownumber` - consistent and precise.

Comment: @KoushikRoy, Thanks for the response. The sql statement is like this ''' Row_Number() over(partition by c1 order by c2 desc, c3 desc) as RowNum. This same is both the queries.

Comment: Both queries give back only one row, but tables are by nature unsorted and their result we s also , so both returned rows could differ , adding a order by would help to get determine results

Comment: @KoushikRoy, yes its the same way  as mentioned above

Comment: @nbk, order by is there in "Row_Number() over(partition by c1 order by c2 desc, c3 desc) as RowNum". If you are mentioning something different, can you please share a example to explain ?

Comment: Is your `ORDER BY` deterministic? Sounds like it isn't.

Comment: The window function row number will do the trick, if a simple order by will work in the subwuery is possible, but I don't believe that it will work

Comment: I just mentioned to guide OP. I dint add details :) its fine, OP can use order by anything that he/she wants.